# how to resolve these problems to install synaptic package manger in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Comment: swathi gaaru , are you trying with sudo ?

Answer (score 0):

open your terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+ <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and paste these commands one-by-one.

```
    sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
    sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/lock
    sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

hope that helps.